# Android instrumentation tests - "Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo"

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to run instrumentation tests on Android ( or Espresso tests for that matter ). The error that I'm getting both from Android Studio and console is:

```
Tests on Nexus_5X_API_23_2(AVD) - 6.0 failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for:



ComponentInfo{com.android.example.country1.demo.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[Nexus_5X_API_23_2(AVD) - 6.0] FAILED
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0rc3'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionName "1"
        versionCode 1
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testProguardFile 'proguard-test-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix ".debug"
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
        }

        release {
           minifyEnabled true // this is a default setting
           useProguard true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "version", "country"

    productFlavors {
        country1 {
            dimension "country1"
            applicationId "com.android.example.country1"
            proguardFile 'src/country1/proguard-country1.pro'
        }
        country2 {
            dimension "country2"
            applicationId "com.android.example.country2"
            proguardFile 'src/country2/proguard-country2.pro'
        }
        demo {
            dimension "version"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "version"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def flavorString = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getFlavorName()
        def mergedFlavour = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getMergedFlavor();

        if (flavorString.toLowerCase().contains("democountry1")) {
            mergedFlavour.setApplicationId("com.android.example.country1.demo")
            mergedFlavour.versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + ".country1.demo";
            ...
        }
        if (flavorString.toLowerCase().contains("prodcountry1")) {
            mergedFlavour.setApplicationId("com.android.example.country1")
            mergedFlavour.versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + ".country1";
            ...
        }
        if (flavorString.toLowerCase().contains("democountry2")) {
            mergedFlavour.setApplicationId("com.android.example.country2.demo")
            mergedFlavour.versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + ".country2.demo";
            ...
        }
        if (flavorString.toLowerCase().contains("prodcountry2")) {
            mergedFlavour.setApplicationId("com.android.example.country2")
            mergedFlavour.versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + ".country2";
            ...
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
    }
}


def props = new Properties()
if (rootProject.file("release.properties").exists()) {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("release.properties")))
    android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile rootProject.file(props.keyStore)
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword props.storePassword
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias props.keyAlias
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword props.keyPassword
} else {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = 'storePassword'
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = 'keyAlias'
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = 'keyPassword'
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.0.2'
    ...

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.5.1'
    //Version resolutins
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
}
```

Note: I know there are a lot of similar questions but after a couple of days of searching and trying solutions I have not found something that works for me.

**UPDATE :**

Instrumentation test case:

```
public class RegulatorRestApiAdapterTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

private MockRetrofit mockRetrofit;
private Retrofit retrofit;

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://test.com")
            .client(new OkHttpClient())
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    NetworkBehavior behavior = NetworkBehavior.create();

    mockRetrofit = new MockRetrofit.Builder(retrofit)
            .networkBehavior(behavior)
            .build();
}


@SmallTest
public void testEcho() throws Exception {
    BehaviorDelegate<BackendRestApi> delegate = mockRetrofit.create(BackendRestApi.class);
    RegulatorRestApi mockBackendRestApi = new MockBackendRestApi(delegate);

    Echo echo = new Echo();
    echo.setEchoRequest("EchoString");

    //Actual Test
    Call<Echo> call = mockBackendRestApi .echo(echo);
    Response<Echo> echoResponse = call.execute();

    //Asserting response
    Assert.assertTrue(echoResponse.isSuccessful());
    Assert.assertEquals("EchoString", echoResponse.body().getEchoResponse());
}
}
```

Espresso test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class EspressoTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void findViewPerformActionAndCheckAssertion() {
        // Find Button and Click on it
        onView(withId(R.id.numpad_ok)).perform(click());

        // Find TextView and verify the correct text that is displayed
        onView(withId(R.id.text_view_rocks)).check(matches(withText(
           mActivityRule.getActivity().getString(R.string.android_testing_rocks))));
    }
}
```

Both tests fail with the same error and code of neither reaches execution. I'm using Android version 6 and successfully execute Instrumentation and Espresso test examples from the Internet on the same emulator.

Comment: Can you give an example of how your an instrumenttion test is looking. Because the issue can be from 1000 reasons. Also what version of Android studio you are using?

Comment: Updated in question.

Comment: Run this command and you'll see instrumented apps - `adb shell pm list instrumentation`. After try to run tests based on the results and double check that before running tests you have both test and app under test installed.

Comment: @Denys - thanks! Before I saw your comment I already had the solution figured out. Indeed running the command showed me exactly what I observed by checking the installed packages on the device. The test application ID was missing the ".demo" section. What puzzles me here is that the test log in AS showed package names that I expected ( including ".demo" section and everything ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to finally resolve it. It might be useful to someone else so I'm posting here.

The way that I was setting application ID was interfering with test application. Although in Android Studio it looked like it was installing application with correct package name when I checked on the device itself the test application ID was lacking ".demo" from "version" flavor dimension.

I made use of the newly introduced ( for flavors )

```
applicationIdSuffix = ".demo"
```

Source : http://android-developers.blogspot.bg/2015/12/leveraging-product-flavors-in-android.html

Here is the modified section of my build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    versionName "1"
    versionCode 1
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    testProguardFile 'proguard-test-rules.pro'
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix ".debug"
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
    }

    release {
       minifyEnabled true // this is a default setting
       useProguard true
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

flavorDimensions "country", "version"

productFlavors {
    country1 {
        dimension "country1"
        applicationIdSuffix = ".country1"
        proguardFile 'src/country1/proguard-country1.pro'
    }
    country2 {
        dimension "country2"
        applicationIdSuffix = ".country2"
        proguardFile 'src/country2/proguard-country2.pro'
    }
    demo {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix = ".demo"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "version"
    }
}
```

So far I don't think

> versionNameSuffix

is usable with flavors so the code below remains.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavorString = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getFlavorName()
    def mergedFlavour = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getMergedFlavor();

    if (flavorString.toLowerCase().contains("country1demo")) {
        mergedFlavour.versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + ".country1.demo";
        ...
    }
    if (flavorString.toLowerCase().contains("country1prod")) {
        mergedFlavour.versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + ".country1";
        ...
    }
    if (flavorString.toLowerCase().contains("country2demo")) {
        mergedFlavour.versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + ".country2.demo";
        ...
    }
    if (flavorString.toLowerCase().contains("country2prod")) {
        mergedFlavour.versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + ".country2";
        ...
    }
}
```